# Creating a priority_queue of packaged_tasks?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a queue of packaged tasks and get their results from futures.  I'm using a condition variable queue presented in Stroustrup C++ 4th Ed Chapter 42 and his idea of using this queue for packaged tasks on Page 1241.  Unfortunately, I'm running into some compilation errors.  Appreciate if anyone has any guidance on getting this code working to demonstrate the idea.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <queue>
#include <future>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class SQ {
public:
    void put(const T& val);
    void put(T&& val);
    void get(T& val);  // T * const v;
private:
    mutex mtx;
    condition_variable cond;
    priority_queue<T> q;
};

template<typename T>
void SQ<T>::put(const T& val)
{
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lck(mtx);
        while (q.size() > 3) // no q bigger than
            cond.wait(lck);
        q.push(val);
    }
    cond.notify_one();
}

template<typename T>
void SQ<T>::put(T&& val)
{
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lck(mtx);
        while (q.size() > 3) // no q bigger than
            cond.wait(lck);
        q.push(forward<T&&>(val));
    }
    cond.notify_one();
}

template<typename T>
void SQ<T>::get(T& val)
{
    unique_lock<mutex> lck(mtx);
    while (q.empty())
        cond.wait(lck);
    val = move(q.top());
    q.pop();
    lck.unlock();
    cond.notify_all();
}

struct QP {
    packaged_task<int(int)> pt;
    int pri;
};
bool operator<(const QP& a, const QP& b)
{
    return a.pri < b.pri;
}

SQ<QP> mq;

#include <random>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std::chrono;
default_random_engine gen(random_device{}());
uniform_int_distribution<int> p{0, 50};

int f(int i) { return i; }

void producer()
{
    vector<future<int>> fv;
    int i = 5;
    while (i--) {
        QP m{packaged_task<int(int)>{f}};
        fv.push_back(m.pt.get_future());
        mq.put(move(m));
        this_thread::sleep_for(milliseconds{p(gen)});
    }

    // get the results
    for (auto& p : fv)
        cout << p.get() << '\n';
}

mutex cout_lock;
void consumer()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
        QP m;
        mq.get(m);
#if 0
        {
            lock_guard<mutex> l{cout_lock};
            cout << this_thread::get_id() << ": " << '\n';
        }
#endif
        this_thread::sleep_for(milliseconds{p(gen)});
        m.pt(i++);
    }
}

int main()
{
    thread t0{consumer};
    thread t1{producer};

    t0.join(); t1.join();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation:

```
clang++ -Wall -pedantic -std=c++11 -lpthread test264.cc && ./a.out
test264.cc:52:9: error: object of type 'QP' cannot be assigned because its copy
      assignment operator is implicitly deleted
    val = move(q.top());
        ^
test264.cc:99:12: note: in instantiation of member function 'SQ<QP>::get' requested
      here
        mq.get(m);
           ^
test264.cc:59:29: note: copy assignment operator of 'QP' is implicitly deleted
      because field 'pt' has a deleted copy assignment operator
    packaged_task<int(int)> pt;
                            ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/future:1517:22: note: 
      'operator=' has been explicitly marked deleted here
      packaged_task& operator=(const packaged_task&) = delete;
                     ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219582/discussion-on-question-by-notaorb-creating-a-priority-queue-of-packaged-tasks).

Answer (score 0):

The use of `priority_queue` cannot work with `packaged_task` because `packaged_task` can only be moved, not copied.  Therefore, `get` cannot move an element out of the priority_queue.  As a solution, this code based on a standard `queue` is provided and works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <queue>
#include <future>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class SQ {
public:
    void put(const T& val);
    void put(T&& val);
    void get(T& val);  // T * const v;
private:
    mutex mtx;
    condition_variable cond;
    queue<T> q;
};

template<typename T>
void SQ<T>::put(const T& val)
{
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lck(mtx);
        while (q.size() > 3) // no q bigger than
            cond.wait(lck);
        q.push(val);
    }
    cond.notify_one();
}

template<typename T>
void SQ<T>::put(T&& val)
{
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lck(mtx);
        while (q.size() > 3) // no q bigger than
            cond.wait(lck);
        q.push(forward<T&&>(val));
    }
    cond.notify_one();
}

template<typename T>
void SQ<T>::get(T& val)
{
    unique_lock<mutex> lck(mtx);
    while (q.empty())
        cond.wait(lck);
    val = move(q.front());
    q.pop();
    lck.unlock();
    cond.notify_all();
}

struct QP {
    QP() {}
    QP(packaged_task<int(int)> &&pt) : pt{move(pt)} {}
    packaged_task<int(int)> pt;
};

SQ<QP> mq;

#include <random>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std::chrono;
default_random_engine gen(random_device{}());
uniform_int_distribution<int> p{0, 50};

int f(int i) { return i; }

void producer()
{
    vector<future<int>> fv;
    int i = 5;
    while (i--) {
        QP m{packaged_task<int(int)>{f}};
        fv.push_back(m.pt.get_future());
        mq.put(move(m));
        this_thread::sleep_for(milliseconds{p(gen)});
    }

    // get the results
    for (auto& p : fv)
        cout << p.get() << '\n';
}

mutex cout_lock;
void consumer()
{
    while (true) {
        QP m;
        mq.get(m);

        this_thread::sleep_for(milliseconds{p(gen)});
        m.pt(0);
    }
}

int main()
{
    thread t0{consumer};
    thread t1{producer};

    t0.join(); t1.join();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation and results:

```
clang++ -Wall -pedantic -std=c++11 -lpthread test262.cc && ./a.out
0
0
0
0
0
```

Comment: Note that this solution does not order the tasks by priority. They will be processed First in, first out.